# How can I persuade syslog output on console to include timestamps?

Tags: c++, linux, syslog

Consider the following program:

```
#include <syslog.h>

int main()
{
    openlog("test-app", LOG_CONS | LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PERROR | LOG_PID, LOG_USER);
    setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_DEBUG));

    syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Testing!");
}
```

Note the use of `LOG_PERROR`, which emits messages to *stderr* as well as whatever file `syslogd` is configured to fill (in my case, `/var/log/messages`).

[The console output is](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0523dfefe798058):

```
test-app[28072]: Testing!
```

The syslog file contains:

```
Apr 17 13:20:14 cat test-app[28072]: Testing!
```

**Can I configure `syslog` so that the console output contains timestamps also? If so, how?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not doable when using the `syslog` call on it's own. The reason is that the timestamp that you see on the log file is after the log message has been sent to the daemon. It's the syslog daemon that actually performs the addition of the timestamp. The logging daemon is the thing that applies the timestamp.

When you use the `LOG_CONS` and `LOG_PERROR` options the message is sent to the console or stderr without ever getting timestamped because the timestamping does not occur at the point of logging.

Essentially the use of `LOG_CONS` and `LOG_PERROR` bypass the daemon entirely; you would need to modify the implementation of the syslog call itself to add your own timestamp. Thankfully, that's pretty easy as the implementation of the syslog library call is in the glibc source, and [the source isn't terribly complicated](http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/branches/eglibc-2_19/libc/misc/syslog.c?view=markup).

Comment: Modifying glibc makes deployment quite a lot more complicated, though, so this is a shame.

Comment: You don't need to modify glibc, you can implement your own syslog equivalent in a small library and use that in your code. At it's core, all the syslog call does is write a simple message to `/dev/log`, the format of which is `<facility|priority>Message` i.e. get the decimal representation of facility | priority and put it into `<>` and send that to `/dev/log` e.g. user.warn == (1 << 3) | 4 so the message is `<12>Message` will get put into wherever the user.warn messages go. (you can test this using `echo "<12>Message" | socat stdin unix-sendto:/dev/log` to see it being logged

Comment: Yeah, could do. Feels a bit NIH, though; not sure I'd get it past code review for relatively little gain.

Comment: I've got a crummy piece of java code which does that because it was easier than writing a JNI stub to call `syslog`.